# "Bureaucratese" meaning of "Industria [country]" / equivalent of "Made in [country]" or "Product of [country]"

Tags: diferencias-regionales, significado-en-contexto

I have a friend with an item labeled "Industria Argentina" and need to know how to interpret this text, aside from a literal translation. Is it akin to "Made in [country]" or "Product of [country]" or is it something else?

Where would I find a reputable source that explains this meaning?

If "Industria [country]" means something different, then what would be the typical equivalents to "Made in [country]" or "Product of [country]" aside from "Hecho en Mexico" which I am familiar with.

(I'm judging for a contest, it's a long story....)

For example: [https://www.amazon.com/Yerba-Rosamonte-Industria-Argentina-Packaging/dp/B07D189N21](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07D189N21)

[image]

Comment: see https://www.discogs.com/forum/thread/350529 but it's a forum discussion and not a reputable source

Comment: see also https://books.google.com/books?id=0iIZVo5WGxwC&pg=RA22-PA6&lpg=RA22-PA6&dq="industria+argentina"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is something in Argentina called *[Ley de Lealtad Comercial](http://servicios.infoleg.gob.ar/infolegInternet/anexos/15000-19999/19946/texact.htm)* (“Trade Loyalty Law”), which mandates the following:

> ARTICULO 2º — Los productos fabricados en el país y los frutos
>   nacionales, cuando se comercialicen en el país llevarán la indicación
>   Industria Argentina o Producción Argentina.

That is, “Products manufactured in the country and national fruits, when commercialized within the country, will carry the indication *Industria Argentina* or *Producción Argentina*.”

Everything that is made in Argentina has to have that label stamped on it somewhere. (There are other laws and regulations having to do with what proportion of the raw materials, procedures and the like are needed for a product to be considered to be manufactured in Argentina.) So it's a just a compulsory “Made in Argentina” label.

I gather that other Latin American countries also have these kinds of mandatory labelling laws because I've seen them in packages.

Comment: Fun fact: In Mexico there's not have a mandatory labelling regulation. Instead, the "Hecho in Mexico" label that you can see in multiple Mexican goods is actually a registered trademark owned by the Mexican Ministry of Economy (Secretaría de Economía). Manufacturers/producers can only use this trademark by adding the label to their goods/produces if the Ministry of Economics certifies that such product was made in Mexican territory (https://www.dof.gob.mx/nota_detalle.php?codigo=4690647&fecha=08/03/1978).

Comment: @pablodf76 thanks for the explanation + the link to the requirement